# Bootstrap autocomplete result in right column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Edit: I made a bin to show my output right now:
http://jsbin.com/cunuxaqe/6/edit**

For some people this might be super easy, but I can't find the solution.
I have a page with several text fields:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" >
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="width:100%;">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" >
    <br>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="width:50%; margin-left:-15px;">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span>KG</span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="width:52%; ">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span>€</span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <br>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in my text field Company I have an autocomplete function:

```
<script>
    (function($){

  var $project = $('#project');

  var projects = [
    {
      value: "test",
      label: "Test"
    },
    {
      value: "hoi",
      label: "Hoi"
    }
  ];

  $project.autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      $project.val( ui.item.label );
      return false;
    }
  });

  $project.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

    var $li = $('<li class="form-control">'),
        $img = $('<img>');




    $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
    $li.append('<a href="#">');
    $li.find('a').append(item.label);

    return $li.appendTo(ul);
  };


})(jQuery);
  </script>
```

The results are shown in an `<li>` but I would like to show the search result in a column on the right which would be not visible normally.
Can someone help me out? I'm a complete noob when it comes to JQuery and Javascript..

Comment: Edit: I made a bin to show my output right now: http://jsbin.com/cunuxaqe/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option. It sets which element the menu should be appended to.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <form role="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Tags" class="form-control" id="tags">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Initialize the autocomplete with the `appendTo` option specified:

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
  appendTo: '#results',
  minLength: 0,
  source: ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby']
});
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/7ajmxbkh/.

Comment: You may also need to reset some CSS properties (like position) depending on your jQuery UI theme.